# change a string into column with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Col1 Col2
G1 element.1:410022-411732(+):element_element
G1 element.2:678-10098(-):element_element
G1 element.4:6868-9899(-):element_element
G1 element.1:789-1222(+):element_element
G2 element.2:890-1220(-):element_element
G3 element.1:12-678(+):element_element
G3 element.1:1298-3000(-):element_element
G4 element.8:23222-98889(+):element_element
G5 element.1:1233-7789(-):element_element
G5 element.9:23333-23390(+):element_element
```

as you can see the value in Col2 have a specific structure :

the element content are variable : `element.9`:23333-23390(+):`element`_`element`

but the structure is always the same : element.9`:`23333`-`23390`(`+`):`element`_`element

You have always 2 numbers separated by a `-` : element.9:`23333-23390`(+):element_element

and I would like to change the values in Col2 when the sign is = `(-)` by subtracting from the first number 1.

for exemple `element.1:1233-7789(-):element_element`

becomes

```
element.1:1232-7789(-):element_element
```

because `1233-1 = 1232`

here for the all exemple I should get a new df  such as :

```
Col1 Col2
G1 element.1:410022-411732(+):element_element
G1 element.2:677-10098(-):element_element
G1 element.4:6867-9899(-):element_element
G1 element.1:789-1222(+):element_element
G2 element.2:889-1220(-):element_element
G3 element.1:12-678(+):element_element
G3 element.1:1297-3000(-):element_element
G4 element.8:23222-98889(+):element_element
G5 element.1:1232-7789(-):element_element
G5 element.9:23333-23390(+):element_element
```

Thank you for your help

I guess one idea should be to use str.split ? But I do not know how to dealwith it since here I have to `split Col2` into `3 Col2bis column`s :

```
Col1 Col2.1     Col2.2 Col2.3 
G1   element.9: 23333  -23390(+):element_element
```

then to Col2.2

```
df['Col2.2']=df['Col2.2']-1
```

and then fusionate the 3 columns once again

```
df["Col2"] = df["Col2.1"] + df["Col2.2"] + df["Col2.3"]
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC I guess his question is complete,4 different users have attempted to answer. So the downvote wasn't necessary, just my opinion.

Comment: @CavinDsouza That’s not much of an indication that the question is up to standards, there are plenty of poor questions which get answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "pandasic" solution with vectorized operations:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Col1,Col2
G1,element.1:410022-411732(+):element_element
G1,element.2:678-10098(-):element_element
G1,element.4:6868-9899(-):element_element
G1,element.1:789-1222(+):element_element
G2,element.2:890-1220(-):element_element
G3,element.1:12-678(+):element_element
G3,element.1:1298-3000(-):element_element
G4,element.8:23222-98889(+):element_element
G5,element.1:1233-7789(-):element_element
G5,element.9:23333-23390(+):element_element
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',')

extracted = df["Col2"].str.extract(r"([^:]*:)(?P<num>\d+)([^(]*\()(?P<flag>[+-])(\).*)")

extracted["num"] = pd.to_numeric(extracted["num"])
extracted.loc[extracted["flag"] == "-", "num"] -= 1
extracted["num"] = extracted["num"].astype(str)

df["Col2"] = extracted[0].str.cat(extracted.iloc[:, 1:])
```

Comment: Thanks but I get only nan values: ```df["Col2"].str.extract(r"([^:]*:)(?P<num>\d+)([^(]*\()(?P<flag>[+-])(\).*)")
          0  num    2 flag    4
0       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN```

Comment: @Grendel Try to use my code as it is and add one or two of your real lines to `data` to check if it doesn't work at all or only not with your data (be aware that the columns are separated by comma here). For me with Python 3.7.5 it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re
```

So I'm using regex to get all the numbers from the `Col2` string, selecting the middle value, subtracting one and then replacing that value back to the column.

```
def func(x_):
    a = re.findall(r'\d+', x_)[1]
    return x_.replace(a, str(int(a)-1))

# Sample frame
x = StringIO("""Col1,Col2
G1,element.1:410022-411732(+):element_element
G1,element.2:678-10098(-):element_element
G1,element.4:6868-9899(-):element_element
G1,element.1:789-1222(+):element_element
G2,element.2:890-1220(-):element_element
G3,element.1:12-678(+):element_element
G3,element.1:1298-3000(-):element_element
G4,element.8:23222-98889(+):element_element
G5,element.1:1233-7789(-):element_element
G5,element.9:23333-23390(+):element_element
""")


df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=',')
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].apply(lambda x: func(x))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Col1                                        Col2
0   G1  element.1:410021-411732(+):element_element
1   G1      element.2:677-10098(-):element_element
2   G1      element.4:6867-9899(-):element_element
3   G1       element.1:788-1222(+):element_element
4   G2       element.2:889-1220(-):element_element
5   G3         element.1:11-678(+):element_element
6   G3      element.1:1297-3000(-):element_element
7   G4    element.8:23221-98889(+):element_element
8   G5      element.1:1232-7789(-):element_element
9   G5    element.9:23332-23390(+):element_element
```

Comment: Is it always -1? I thought OP wants to subtract the first value?

Comment: @displayname I thought so too, but when I checked his sample output, it seems all the values are one less than original, although, some remain the same.

Comment: A bit slow for a large dataframe.

Comment: @MichaelButscher hmm, but I cannot think of a vectorized way to do this, like split and/or regex seem to be a necessity.

Comment: I do -1 to the first value only when there is ```(-)``` in the string  not for ```(+)```

Comment: @CavinDsouza It needs regex, right, but pandas has e.g. [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for that.

Answer (score -1):

Check if this works for you: The idea is to create a pattern, do the subtraction, and replace the string with pandas' [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method.

```
pat = r"(?P<start>.*\d:)(?P<num>\d+)(?P<end>.*\(-\))"
repl = lambda m: f'{m.group("start")}{int(m.group("num"))-1}{m.group("end")}'
df.Col2 = df.Col2.str.replace(pat,repl)
df

    Col1    Col2
0   G1  element.1:410022-411732(+):element_element
1   G1  element.2:677-10098(-):element_element
2   G1  element.4:6867-9899(-):element_element
3   G1  element.1:789-1222(+):element_element
4   G2  element.2:889-1220(-):element_element
5   G3  element.1:12-678(+):element_element
6   G3  element.1:1297-3000(-):element_element
7   G4  element.8:23222-98889(+):element_element
8   G5  element.1:1232-7789(-):element_element
9   G5  element.9:23333-23390(+):element_element
```

Comment: thank you but the ```element```part can have any content it can always change. So using "el" to detect wont work

Comment: "el" is the group name, and has nothing to do with the content. as long as the content matches the regex pattern for group "el"

Comment: here is an exemple of my real df in col2 ```UCOL01000782.1:1094-1750(-):Canis_lupus``` and when I try the code nothing chang ...

Comment: Ahhh I c... gimme a moment

Comment: @CavinDsouza You are aware that downvotes are a completely normal part of the site, right?

Comment: @AMC if it had a reason yes, I don't see one for this question and the answers, I won't say the question was framed in the best way, there is room for improvement, but what's perfect anyway

Comment: @CavinDsouza In this particular case, the most glaring thing to me is the lack of a clear and specific issue, not even an attempt at solving this, using `Series.str.split` for example, even if it would be slightly unwieldy. OP has given us a list of their requirements, and people are writing their program for them, what's the point of that?